# Is it possible that a process $X$ is $(\mathcal A⊗\mathcal B(I),\mathcal E)$-measurable, but not $(\sigma(X)⊗\mathcal B(I),\mathcal E)$-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces, $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.

> Is it possible that $X$, considered as a map $\Omega\times I\to E$, is $(\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B(I),\mathcal E)$-measurable, but not $(\sigma(X)\otimes\mathcal B(I),\mathcal E)$-measurable?

Note that $\sigma(X)=\sigma(X_t,t\in I)$.

Comment: $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{A}$, so $\sigma(X) \otimes B(I) \subset \mathcal{A} \otimes B(I)$.

Comment: @Mason Yes, sorry, I'm obviously interested in the other direction.